# How to run an Actions on Google test for more than 30 mins?

Tags: actions-on-google

I followed the steps on the following question:
[Make google actions development project preview persist longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088596/make-google-actions-development-project-preview-persist-longer/41205026), but this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Some relevant notes:

- I'm using version 2.0.7 of the gactions cli
- I confirmed @dadykhoff's answer. As of May 17, using "gactions preview" doesn't work anymore. You need to use "gactions test"
- Not sure if it's relevant but my action requires the user to be logged in to Google, so when the test starts I have to link my account and then I can start interacting with the app
- I ran `gactions --verbose test --project {project name} --action_package action.json --preview_mins 2400` and although the test was pushed successfully, it still expired after ~30 mins
- I confirmed from the verbose output that "endTimestamp" is set correctly to 2400 mins from the moment I ran the command

Any ideas on how I can get the test to run longer?

Comment: Tests should last for 30 days by default (have you tried without specifying the preview_mins?). Can you confirm that your project can be found at console.actions.google.com? Also, be aware you can only have one app active at a time per account.

Comment: @LeonNicholls I tried again without specifying preview_mins and confirmed that my project is at console.actions.google.com. The answer I get from the simulator after ~30 mins when I invoke "Talk to {Agent}" is "Sorry, I can't help with that yet."

Comment: Please check if you are using version 1 of the protocol. Version 2 has the fulfillmentApiVersion of 2.

Comment: This is what I see in my debug output: 
POST /v2/users/me/previews/...
User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.0.7 (darwin; amd64; stable/6f4c996f8ee63dc5760c7728f674abe37bfe5fc4)

Comment: Look at the migration guide to make sure you aren't still on version 1: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/migration#migration_for_actions_sdk