# Google Home API.IA for private use on own Home

Tags: private, google-home, assistant

I have created a Google Home agent to control my thermostat. Of course I want to be the only one using and controling it. So I dont want to publish the app.

There is a small tutorial for extending the use of the simulator and even an update for V2. But the V2 update I can't seem te get to work, I get to following error:

> Unable to parse action package: invalid character ',' after top-level
>   value

Did someone else get this to work?

This is the tutorial (scroll down for the update by @dadykhoff)
[Make google actions development project preview persist longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088596/make-google-actions-development-project-preview-persist-longer/41205026#41205026)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. To help you with this question we'll need to get a glimpse on the code. Please share the relevant parts it.

Comment: Are you getting the error when attempting to run the CLI statement or somewhere else?

Comment: The error is from the CLI statement with the action.json.